# Search string in memory within GDB

Tags: gdb, buffer-overflow

I am currently working on memory corruption techniques for a study and especially ROP and ret2libc. I've read many times that for achieving a `system()` call, the address of the string of `/bin/sh` (or equivalent) was required on the stack. I managed to get it when dealing with environment variables, but I wanted to known if the string was present in the libc:

```
$ strings libc-2.22.so  | grep -i /bin/sh
/bin/sh
```

Okay, but when searching the string with the process started, I saw some strange behaviour:

```
user@protostar:/opt/protostar/bin$ gdb -q ./stack6
Reading symbols from /opt/protostar/bin/stack6...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x8048500: file stack6/stack6.c, line 27.
Starting program: /opt/protostar/bin/stack6 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff854) at stack6/stack6.c:27
27  stack6/stack6.c: No such file or directory.
    in stack6/stack6.c
(gdb) find __libc_start_main,+999999,"/bin/sh"
Pattern not found.
(gdb) find __libc_start_main,+99999999,"/bin/sh"
0xb7fba23f
warning: Unable to access target memory at 0xb7fd9647, halting search.
1 pattern found.
(gdb) x/1s 0xb7fba23f
0xb7fba23f:  "KIND in __gen_tempname\""
```

And more strangeness when just searching the "sh" pattern:

```
(gdb) find __libc_start_main,+99999999,"sh"
0xb7fb7a95
0xb7fb821d
warning: Unable to access target memory at 0xb7fdb4a0, halting search.
2 patterns found.
(gdb) x/1s 0xb7fb7a95
0xb7fb7a95:  "getpwuid_r"
(gdb) x/1s 0xb7fb821d
0xb7fb821d:  "sh"
```

In a way, I successfully conducted a ret2libc attack using the string located at 0xb7fb821d, but here are my questions:

- Why did GDB not "really" find the `/bin/sh` pattern?
- Why are matches found by gdb not really matching my search?

I am pretty new to all this stuff, and even if I discovered a lot of tricks related to binary exploitation, I think that I am missing something here.

Comment: You might have better luck over in [Reverse Engineering SE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it's better suited for Reverse Engineering SE.

Comment: Welcome to InfoSec.SE! Security.SE likes to focus on security _architecture_, or the _design_ of secure systems (see [this thread on meta](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/2306/61443) for more discussion). I agree with @RoraΖ that this question is a little too technical and would be a better fit for ReverseEngineering.SE.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Yes, this question _would_ be better suited for reverse engineering, but it got migrated to SO instead [and you're listed as one of the votes for migration]. Any ideas on how that happened? And, is it worth bouncing it twice?

Comment: @CraigEstey I voted to close as Off-Topic. I think once there's 5 votes to close or migrate, it picks the winning reason and shows everybody as having voted for it.

Comment: @CraigEstey, should I move this topic manually to the reversing section ? Can I help in your vote ?

Comment: At this point, the most efficient way [and perhaps only possible way] to migrate this to Reverse Engineering is through moderator action. I've flagged it, with a specific request and details. Moderators are usually pretty good about such things. Now, you should wait a day or two to see what happens. Your question is perfect for and typical of RevEng. So, for the moment, just be patient. Sorry, you're getting bounced around to land on the best site

Comment: Myriam and @CraigEstey, a post cannot be migrated more than once. The best solution here would be for Myriam to delete the post here, and post a new question on Reverse Engineering.

Comment: If you haven't already posted on RevEng, here's a suggestion to save yourself some work. Edit your question here, and select all text within the _edit_ window. Copy it (ctrl-c). Then, abandon the edit. Then ask the question on RevEng. You should be able to paste saved text and you'll get most of your formatting, etc. When, you've posted on RevEng, then delete the question here.